# How to interactively rebase with premade file

Tags: git, github

So I have an app and I am pulling commit SHAs out from some internal processes. I need to open an interactive rebase with these. Is there a way to specify a file to use in an interactive rebase rather than having to type it up? So that I can click a button and the interactive rebase file pops up prepopulated with what I specified rather than what git specified.

Answer (score 2):

No, not exactly—but it's easy enough to get the same *effect*.

Running `git rebase -i` has Git:

- write out an instruction sheet with `pick` commands (and maybe others depending on options);
- invoke the *sequence editor* on the instruction sheet;
- if and when the sequence editor exits with a success indication, reads back the instruction sheet and begins executing the instructions, which use the *Git editor* if they need to run an editor.

You can simply define the sequence editor to be a program (or shell script) that you write, that copies your prepared instructions *over* the existing instruction sheet, then exits with status 0 (indicating success).  That tells Git that you, the person or thing driving the rebase, have successfully provided the updated instructions.  If the updated instructions are all-new and completely different from what `git rebase -i` generated, well, so what?  Git is just going to obey those instructions.

To choose a different sequence editor while leaving the standard Git editor unchanged, either set the environment variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` or use `git -c sequence.editor=name rebase -i`.  Note that `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` overrides `sequence.editor`, and is trivial to set in bash-style syntax since you just run:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=foo git rebase -i
```

(though you should provide a full, or at least full-ish, path name for `foo` to make sure you get the right executable).  Remember that the arguments *to* the sequence editor consist solely of the path name of the instruction sheet file, so you'll need to smuggle the path name of your pre-computed instructions in somehow.  Generally this means it's either either hard-coded in the executable shell script you write out before invoking `git rebase -i`, or provided via an environment variable.